# Silverlight TimePicker / ChildWindow / DataTemplate combination causes UI freeze

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm working on a Silverlight project, using MVVM, and I've run into a problem that only appears to occur under some fairly specific situations. I've tried to strip everything down as much as possible so only the important parts are left.

The Scenario:

- A standard Silverlight `ChildWindow`
- The `ChildWindow` has a `Selector` Control (e.g. a `ComboBox` or a `ListBox`).
- The `ChildWindow` has a `ContentPresenter`

  - The `Content` of this `ContentPresenter` is bound to the `SelectedValue` of the above mentioned `Selector` Control (In reality it is bound to a ViewModel property, but for testing purposes this is not necessary).
  - The `ContentPresenter` uses a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx) to determine it's `ContentTemplate`
- The `Selector` Control contains the `string` values "A" and "B" which correspond to `DataTemplate`s "TemplateA" and "TemplateB".
- "TemplateB" contains a `TimePicker` control.

The Problem:

After selecting "B" (therefore loading "TemplateB"), the next time you try to change the selected template, the host webpage will freeze. No exception is thrown and no information is given.

Notes:

- Everything works fine outside of a `ChildWindow`.
- Everything works fine if none of the templates contain a `TimePicker` control.
- The `TimePicker` control appears to work fine if it is displayed without using a `ContentPresenter`/`DataTemplateSelector`.
- Ive looked at [TimePicker in ChildWindow causes an exception](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/3565) on the Silverlight Toolkit CodePlex page. That particular issue appears to be resolved and I've tried implementing [the suggested workaround](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/108539/297083.aspx) just to be sure, and it has no effect.

Code to reproduce the problem:

`ChildWindow` XAML:

```xml
<controls:ChildWindow
x:Class="TimePickerProblem.ChildWindow1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimePickerProblem"
Width="400"
Height="300"
Title="ChildWindow1">
<controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel
        x:Key="vm" />
</controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="White"
        DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <StackPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="ComboBox"
                Margin="20"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}" />
            <ContentPresenter
                Content="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}">
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:TemplateSelector
                            Content="{Binding}">
                            <local:TemplateSelector.TemplateA>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Text="Hello from A" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:TemplateSelector.TemplateA>
                            <local:TemplateSelector.TemplateB>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:TimePicker />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:TemplateSelector.TemplateB>
                        </local:TemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="CancelButton"
        Content="Cancel"
        Click="CancelButton_Click"
        Width="75"
        Height="23"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,12,0,0"
        Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button
        x:Name="OKButton"
        Content="OK"
        Click="OKButton_Click"
        Width="75"
        Height="23"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,12,79,0"
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<string> Templates { get { return new List<string>() { "a", "b" }; } }
```

DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      string value = (string)item;

      switch (value.ToLower())
      {
        case "a":
          return TemplateA;
        case "b":
          return TemplateB;
        default:
          return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger, breaking the execution and analyzing call stacks on threads (especially Main Thread)? Are they clean or maybe some are 'in a Sleep, Wait or Join'?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried in SL5, and couldn't reproduce your problem. If I've time, I will try SL4. Do you have any styles present that might cause a problem?

If you are describing a situation where overlay appears after dismissing ChildWindow, then it is known bug. Here's a workaround.

```
ChildWindow w = new MyChildWindow();
w.Closed += (s, eargs) => { Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true); };
w.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this does not seem to have any effect. The hang occurs before the window closed event would be fired.